# Showing $\rho$ is a metric inside a metric space $(X, d)$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $B(X)$ be the family of closed, bounded, nonempty subsets of $X$. For $A, B ∈ B(X)$ let

$$ρ(A, B) := \max\{\sup_{b \in B} d(b, A),\ \sup_{a \in A} d(a, B)\},$$

where $d(x, A) = \inf\{d(x, a) : a ∈ A\}$ for $x ∈ X$ and $A ⊂ X$.

How can I show that $ρ$ is a metric on $B(X)$?

Comment: Validate the axioms.

Comment: You know that this is called [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance), don't you?

Comment: Do you think it would be enough to show the triangle inequality?

Comment: E.g. [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20020623095720/http://www-math.mit.edu/phase2/UJM/vol1/HAUSF.PDF) or [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/library/sternberg/slides/1180910.pdf)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Except that the Hausdorff distance is a metric on the family of all compact subsets.

Comment: @freakish closed and bounded is enough.